# Validating a tag name in a git repository

Tags: git, git-tag

I have 13 git remote repositories. In my local machine I have a folder to which all the remote repositories are "added" using `git remote add` command. 
Now I want to find whether a tag "V1.0" is present in a particular remote repository.

I tried with: `git rev-list V1.0`

But in this command we cant specify the remote repository name.

Is there a command similar to `git rev-list` in which we can specify the remote repository name also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`ls-remote`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-ls-remote.html) subcommand should do what you want:

```
git ls-remote --tags https://git.example.com/repo.git "V1.0"
```